# ApexDevNet in the remote site

Tags: administration, security, remote-access

Just found a remote site in the Dev Org. I didn't add it before. What is the remote site "ApexDevNet" ?

Can we just disable it ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It exists as part of a standard set of customizations that are deployed along with all newly created developer edition orgs. You'll also notice a visualforce page called StartHere, and some apex classes (which amusingly violate a number of best practices) as well.

These show the default "start here" you see when initially logging in, and this remote site setting exists to allow these to fetch the content that's displayed there.

You can, and in nearly all cases should, delete both the remote site setting as well as the security-violating apex and visualforce components.